# Need help finding a Sutta in which the Buddha details the rebirth destination of a soldier

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, sutras, sutta-reference

There is one specific Sutta in which the Buddha details the rebirth destination of a patriotic soldier who dies in battle for the sake of his country? Can someone please help me find it. Metta to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [Yodhajiva Sutta (SN 42.3)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn42/sn42.003.than.html)

> When a warrior strives & exerts himself in battle, his mind is already seized, debased, & misdirected by the thought: 'May these beings be struck down or slaughtered or annihilated or destroyed. May they not exist.' If others then strike him down & slay him while he is thus striving & exerting himself in battle, then with the breakup of the body, after death, he is reborn in the hell called the realm of those slain in battle. But if he holds such a view as this: 'When a warrior strives & exerts himself in battle, if others then strike him down & slay him while he is striving & exerting himself in battle, then with the breakup of the body, after death, he is reborn in the company of devas slain in battle,' that is his wrong view. Now, there are two destinations for a person with wrong view, I tell you: either hell or the animal womb.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

About patriotically protecting the nation.

> ‘But sire, what is the noble duty of a wheel-turning monarch?’
>
> ‘Well then, my dear, relying only on principle (dhamma) honoring,
> respecting and venerating principle, having principle as your flag,
> banner and authority—**provide just protection and security** for your
> court, **troops**, aristocrats, vassals, brahmins and householders, people
> of town and country, ascetics and brahmins, beasts and birds.
>
> [DN 26](https://suttacentral.net/dn26/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=none&highlight=true&script=latin)

Maybe [Yodhajiva Sutta (SN 42.3)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn42/sn42.003.than.html) is not about patriotic soldier who dies in battle for the sake of his country.

Comment: I read a suggestion somewhere once, that references to a "wheel-turning monarch" might have been there to flatter or to refer to Ashoka.

Comment: @Dhamma Dhatu Thank you kind sir, for your response. But the question of mine is from a soldier's vantage point and his/her kammic repercussions, it is not about the monarch or a king. Don't you think there is a difference there?

Comment: The monarchs & kings were warrior caste. You asked about a "nation" or  "patriotism". If there is any confusion, it is in your question. The Buddha said: let none see the omissions and commissions of others. But let one see one's own acts, done and undone.